# parallel loop to build dataframe

Tags: r, loops

The other day I [answered my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35758003/841405) about how to loop through a dataframe to get all combinations of my variables in sets of 2, 3, 4, and 5, calculate a scale score, and assess some psychometrics.

It works, but it's really slow for my actual use case of all 616,645 combinations of 20 variables in sets of 2-10.

I don't have much experience running in parallel, but I think a possible solution is to use the `foreach` and `doParallel` packages as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28029445/841405). Unfortunately, I am not quite seeing how to adapt this idea to my use case.

Here is my actual code with a much smaller toy example that only takes seconds to run:

```
library(gtools)
library(OptimalCutpoints)

# new packages to run loop in parallel
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(detectCores())  

# create fake data
  df <- data.frame(class=sample(0:1, 50, replace=T),
                   v01=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v02=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v03=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v04=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v05=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T))

# combinations
  dfoc <- as.data.frame(NULL)
  ri <- 1

  # I think the outer loop should somehow use 
  #    foreach(i=2:(length(df)-1)) %:%
  # and then the inner loop use
  #    foreach(r=1:nrow(p)) %dopar%
  # but I'm not sure of the assignment in either case
  # I want to build dfoc each iteration

  for (i in 2:(length(df)-1)) {  
    p <- combinations(n = length(df)-1, r = i, v = names(df[2:(length(df))]))
    for (r in 1:nrow(p)) {
      keep <- c("class", p[r,])
      v <- keep[-1]
      df_ <- df[, keep]
      df_$T <- rowSums(df_[,2:length(keep)])
      oc <- summary(optimal.cutpoints(X = "T", 
                                      status = "class",
                                      tag.healthy = 0,
                                      methods = "SpEqualSe",
                                      data = df_,
                                      control = control.cutpoints(),
                                      ci.fit = TRUE,
                                      conf.level = 0.95, 
                                      trace = FALSE))
      dfoc[ri,1] <- i                                    # number vars in set
      dfoc[ri,2] <- r                                    # permutation number
      dfoc[ri,3] <- paste(v, collapse=",")               # var names in set
      dfoc[ri,4] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][1]     # cutoff
      dfoc[ri,5] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][2]     # sen
      dfoc[ri,6] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][3]     # spe
      dfoc[ri,7] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][4]     # ppv
      dfoc[ri,8] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][5]     # npv
      dfoc[ri,9] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][2,2]   # sen l95
      dfoc[ri,10] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][2,3]  # sen u95
      dfoc[ri,11] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][3,2]  # spe l95
      dfoc[ri,12] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][3,3]  # spe u95
      dfoc[ri,13] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][4,2]  # ppv l95
      dfoc[ri,14] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][4,3]  # ppv u95
      dfoc[ri,15] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][5,2]  # npv l95
      dfoc[ri,16] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][5,3]  # npv u95
      dfoc[ri,17] <- oc$p.table$Global$AUC_CI               # auc
      ri <- ri+1
      remove(df_)
      remove(keep)
      remove(v)
      remove(oc)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague showed me how to vectorize and simplify:

```
## packages
library(gtools)
library(OptimalCutpoints)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(detectCores())

## create fake data
df <- data.frame(class=sample(0:1, 50, replace=T),
                 v01=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                 v02=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                 v03=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                 v04=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                 v05=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T))

## all combinations in one data frame
## 2:5 is the number of items
combos <- do.call(rbind, lapply(2:5, function(s) {
  data.frame(
    NItems = s,
    Vars = apply(combinations(
    n = length(df)-1,
    r = s,
    v = names(df[2:(length(df))])
  ), 1, paste, collapse = ","), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}))

## function
combo <- function(p, d) {
  keep <- c("class", unlist(strsplit(p[1, "Vars"], ",")))
  v <- keep[-1]
  d_ <- d[, keep]
  d_$T <- rowSums(d_[,2:length(keep)])
  oc <- summary(optimal.cutpoints(X = "T",
                                  status = "class",
                                  tag.healthy = 0,
                                  methods = "SpEqualSe",
                                  data = d_,
                                  control = control.cutpoints(),
                                  ci.fit = TRUE,
                                  conf.level = 0.95,
                                  trace = FALSE))

  out <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]]

  data.frame(
    cutoff = out[1],     # cutoff
    sen = out[2],     # sen
    spe = out[3],     # spe
    ppv = out[4],     # ppv
    npv = out[5],     # npv
    senl95 = out[2,2],   # sen l95
    senu95 = out[2,3],  # sen u95
    spel95 = out[3,2],  # spe l95
    speu95 = out[3,3],  # spe u95
    ppvl95 = out[4,2],  # ppv l95
    ppvu95 = out[4,3],  # ppv u95
    npvl95 = out[5,2],  # npv l95
    npvu95 = out[5,3],  # npv u95
    auc = oc$p.table$Global$AUC_CI, # auc
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}


## not parallel
system.time(
  y <- foreach(r=1:nrow(combos), .combine=rbind) %do% combo(combos[r, , drop=FALSE], df)
)
finalDF <- cbind(combos, y)

## parallel
system.time(
  y2 <- foreach(r=1:nrow(combos), .combine=rbind) %dopar% combo(combos[r, , drop=FALSE], df)
)
finalDF2 <- cbind(combos, y2)

## test equal
all.equal(y, y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach reduced the runtime for my actual use case (>600k combinations) from 2+ days to 2+ hours.

```
# packages  
  library(gtools)
  library(OptimalCutpoints)
  library(foreach)
  library(doParallel)
  registerDoParallel(detectCores())  

# create fake data
  df <- data.frame(class=sample(0:1, 50, replace=T),
                   v01=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v02=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v03=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v04=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T),
                   v05=sample(0:3, 50, replace=T))

# combinations
  dfoc <- as.data.frame(NULL)
  ri <- 1

# outer function
  outer <- function(s, d) {
    p <- combinations(n = length(d)-1, r = s, v = names(d[2:(length(d))]))
    return(p)
  } 

# inner function
  combo <- function(i, r, p, d) {
    keep <- c("class", p[r,])
    v <- keep[-1]
    d_ <- d[, keep]
    d_$T <- rowSums(d_[,2:length(keep)])
    oc <- summary(optimal.cutpoints(X = "T", 
                                    status = "class",
                                    tag.healthy = 0,
                                    methods = "SpEqualSe",
                                    data = d_,
                                    control = control.cutpoints(),
                                    ci.fit = TRUE,
                                    conf.level = 0.95, 
                                    trace = FALSE))
    dfoc[ri,1] <- i                                    # number vars in set
    dfoc[ri,2] <- r                                    # permutation number
    dfoc[ri,3] <- paste(v, collapse=",")               # var names in set
    dfoc[ri,4] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][1]     # cutoff
    dfoc[ri,5] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][2]     # sen
    dfoc[ri,6] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][3]     # spe
    dfoc[ri,7] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][4]     # ppv
    dfoc[ri,8] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][5]     # npv
    dfoc[ri,9] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][2,2]   # sen l95
    dfoc[ri,10] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][2,3]  # sen u95
    dfoc[ri,11] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][3,2]  # spe l95
    dfoc[ri,12] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][3,3]  # spe u95
    dfoc[ri,13] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][4,2]  # ppv l95
    dfoc[ri,14] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][4,3]  # ppv u95
    dfoc[ri,15] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][5,2]  # npv l95
    dfoc[ri,16] <- oc$p.table$Global$SpEqualSe[[1]][5,3]  # npv u95
    dfoc[ri,17] <- oc$p.table$Global$AUC_CI               # auc
    ri <- ri+1
    remove(d_)
    remove(keep)
    remove(v)
    remove(oc)
    return(dfoc)
  }

# parallel
  system.time(
  y <- foreach(s=2:5) %do% {
    p <- outer(s, df)
    x <- foreach(r=1:nrow(p), .combine=rbind) %dopar% combo(s, r, p, df)
  }
  )

# convert to data frame
  finalDF <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, y)
```